# Powershell get property of children together

Tags: powershell, object, collections

I have Powershell object that holds a collection of serial numbers. I'd like to return all serial numbers together using a system method instead of looping through them and making a new array or collection.

Trying:

```
PS C:> $serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years | select Name, @{n='SerialNumbers';e={$_.Value.SerialNumbers}}
```

Results in no output:

```
Name SerialNumbers
---- -------------
```

This also results in no output:

```
$serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years | % {$_.Value.SerialNumbers}
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years

Name Value
---- -----
1981 {SerialNumbers}
1975 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
1976 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
1985 {SerialNumbers}
1974 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
1977 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
1978 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
1980 {SerialNumbers, StartSerialNumber, EndSerialNumber, PlaceholderLength}
```

Is there a Powershell method to return a common property, in my case `SerialNumbers`, of all children together?

Here is the output of the underlying children:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years.'1981'

Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
SerialNumbers                  {System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow...}

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years.'1981'.SerialNumbers

serial_number
-------------
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

This is what I've resorted to:

```
ForEach ($year in $serialNumbersByModel.model.Years.keys) {
    $serialNumbersByModel.model.Years.$year.SerialNumbers
}
```

Comment: `$serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years | select Name, @{n='SerialNumbers';e={$_.Value.SerialNumbers}}`

Comment: `$serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years |%{$_.Value.SerialNumbers}`

Comment: Thank you.  These result empty.  I can't see where the iteration of the children breaks down.  Could the key be the problem?

Comment: `$serialNumbersByModel.'3910101'.Years.Values.SerialNumbers`